# I have a question about the article (a town or the town)

Tags: grammar, articles

In this sentence:

> She is in Burford now, - little town near London.

Which article do we use? "a little town" or "the little town?"

Answer (score 5):

"A little town near London" implies one of many little towns near London.
"The little town near London" implies one particular Burford that is near London as opposed to other Burfords around the country or the world.
In general, if there is no ambiguity, "a" would normally be used.

Comment: Agreed.  We might say "I live in Paris - the city in Texas, not the one in France."

Comment: So in this case, we use @She is in Burford now, a little town near London.@, right?

Comment: As Peter says, it depends which meaning you want to convey!

Comment: I see. And what do you think about this sentence: @Pete has got a dark flat in town. In the village he has got a big house.@
In this example we don't use any article to "town" but we say "In the village"

Comment: +1 Further, "the little town near London" might also mean there's only one little town near London.

Comment: @Venro - *Town* follows a slightly different usage than other municipal divisions.  Things can be described as *uptown, downtown, crosstown, and midtown,* all of which are valid compound words. No such combinations exist for village or city.  These constructs are not idiomatic with an article.  *I drove to **the** downtown,* does not work.  As a result *town* becomes idiomatic without an article.  *I'm going to town.  I am coming from town.  I drove through town.*

Comment: In your sentence, both _town_ and _the village_ must refer to places that have already been mentioned.

Comment: @gotube Agreed it might, but, as we all know, there are dozens if not hundreds of "little towns" near London. It all depends on your definition of "little" (Population less than ????) and "near". I visit the real Burford quite frequently and it's about 71 miles from Marble Arch (the traditional point in London from which measurements of distance are taken) so by UK standards it isn't "near" at all. But all this is irrelevant regarding the OP's question. Note, I cannot find any other Burfords anywhere on Google Maps, so the one in Oxfordshire is it.

Comment: @Venro Nothing to do with your question, but what are you trying to achieve with the @ symbol in your comments? If it is italics then a pair of single asterisks enclosing the text is used and if it is to embolden then a pair of double asterisks does the trick.

Comment: Thank for you answers!

Answer (score 0):

Correct: She is in Burford now, **a** little town near London.

She is in Burford now, *a* little town near London. (Perhaps one of many towns near London.)

She is in Burford now, *the* little town near London. (only one town near London,)